$f:A\subseteq \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ maps closed sets to closed sets.
Can you take a look at my proof, please?
Let $f:A\subseteq\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x)=(x,x^2)$ where $A$ is a closed set and $f$ is continuous in $A$. Show that $f$ maps closed sets to closed sets.
According to a theorem, we have that $f[\bar{A}]\subseteq \overline{f[A]}, \forall A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$
Because $A$ is closed set, $A=\bar{A}$ and so we have $f[\bar{A}]=f[A]$, then $f[A]\subseteq \overline{f[A]}$. So we need to show that $\overline{f[A]}\subseteq f[A]$
Let $\vec{y}_0\in \overline{f[A]}$. There exists $\{\vec{y}_k\}\subseteq f[A]$ such that $\{\vec{y}_k\}\to \vec{y}_0$ and if $x_k\in A$, then $f(x_k)=\vec{y}_k$, then $\{x_k\}$ is contained in $A$ and is bounded and so, is convergent. There exists a convergent subsequence $\{x_{k_l}\}$ and if $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$ is such that $\{x_{k_l}\}\to x_0$ when $l\to \infty$, then $x_0\in A$ and knowing that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, we have that $\{f(x_{k_l})=\vec{y}_{k_l}\to f(x_0)\}$ when $l\to \infty$. And because $\{\vec{y}_{k_l}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{\vec{y}_k\}$, then $\{\vec{y}_{k_l}\to \vec{y}_0\}$ and because the convergence point of a sequence is unique, $\vec{y}_0=f(x_0)$ wich shows that $\vec{y}_0\in f[A]$

There should be some clarification needed to prove $x_k$ is bounded.

the question is ambigus... does $f:A\to \mathbb R^2$ or $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2$ ? If $f:A\to \mathbb R^2$, you always use the set $A$, are these two $A$ the same ?

You didn't use the definition of $f$ so the proof can't be right.

You are using that $(x_k)_k$ is bounded. This is in general not the case (continous maps with this property are called proper) and you need to prove that your map has this property (which is fairly easy in your case).

We consider the function
$ f :\, \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2, x\mapsto (x,x^2)$
and claim it is a topological embedding. That is, $f(\mathbb{R})$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. This can be seen, for example, by explicitly writing down its continuous inverse, i.e. the projection map $(x,y)\mapsto x$.
Next, note $f(\mathbb{R})$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, for it is the fiber $F^{-1}(0)$ of the continuous function
$F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}, (x,y) \mapsto y-x^2$.
To conclude all of this, we consider a set $B$ closed in $A$. Because $A$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$, $B$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$. Then $f(B)$ is closed in $f(\mathbb{R})$. Since $f(\mathbb{R})$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$, we've proved $f(B)$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

As for your proof, well, the problem is you can't assure $x_k$ is bounded. If $A$ is bounded, then $A$ is compact, and discussion above is redundant. Continuous injections between Hausdorff spaces always take compact sets to compact sets, homeomorphically. Another classical result is any continuous function from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a closed map.
Of course beginners would be curious about some concrete counterexamples, where a countinuous map fails to become a closed one. $\arctan$ takes $\mathbb{R}$ to a non-closed interval $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$.

OP's proof can be made rigorous. If $(y_n, y_n^2)_n$ converges in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $(y_n)_n$ is bounded.

@SeverinSchraven Certainly. In fact, everything comes down to a fact that $f$ is a graph. With help of the same method demonstrated in my answer (and maybe OP's), one can show that the graph $F: x\mapsto (x,f(x))$ of a continuous function $f: \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a topological embedding with closed image.

Surely, I just meant to say that the OPs proof can be made rigorous without much thought or fancy nomenclature :)
